# Google Maps JavaScript API markers & infowindows

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm facing an issue with the `open` method on `infoWindow` object.

I want to set all my map utility objects dynamically but when the `open` method is called it raises me an error because the `infoWindow` object associated is `undefined`.

Here is my code :

```
    // Markers & infoWindows
    var markers = [];
    var infoWindows = [];

    for(var i=0; i<myList.length; i++) {
        markers.push(
            new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myList[i].coord,
                map: map,
                title: myList[i].city
            })
        );
        infoWindows.push(
            new google.maps.InfoWindow({
               content: myList[i].address
            })
        );
        markers[i].addListener('click', function() {
            infoWindows[i].open(map, markers[i]);
        });
    }
```

[ Where `myList` is just an arry of JSON formated objects. ]

All the markers and infoWindows are well set. I can access their properties and print them to the console.

But as I said the `infoWindows[i]` is typed undefined so the `open` method isn't found. A contrario I can access and print the `content` attribute of this `infoWindows[i]` object. Seems weird to me...

If someone is able to explain me I will be happy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related question: [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

When the loop completes `i` is left at `infoWindows.length`, which is past the end of the array. One way to fix it is with function closure on `i`:

```
markers[i].addListener('click', (function(i) {
return function() {
  infoWindows[i].open(map, markers[i]);
}}(i)));
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ut26hx9u/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  // Markers & infoWindows
  var markers = [];
  var infoWindows = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    markers.push(
      new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myList[i].coord,
        map: map,
        title: myList[i].city
      })
    );
    infoWindows.push(
      new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: myList[i].address
      })
    );
    markers[i].addListener('click', (function(i) {
      return function() {
        infoWindows[i].open(map, markers[i]);
      }
    }(i)));

    bounds.extend(markers[i].getPosition());
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
var myList = [{
  coord: {
    lat: 42,
    lng: -72
  },
  city: "Somewhere",
  address: "Somewhere"
}, {
  coord: {
    lat: 40.7127837,
    lng: -74.0059413
  },
  city: "New York, NY, USA",
  address: "New York, NY, USA"
}, {
  coord: {
    lat: 40.735657,
    lng: -74.1723667
  },
  city: "Newark, NJ, USA",
  address: "Newark, NJ, USA"
}];
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```